# What about L5.5 Package Discovery feature on OC?

Tags: octobercms

This new feature really works on latest OctoberCMS build ?
If yes, works for installed from composer, web installer or both?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Try installing a package which uses auto-discovery and sees the results. FYI I believe it does work normally as expected

Comment: @Nick I just add `"werneckbh/laravel-qr-code":    "0.1.*"` to `composer.json`. 
First, Ide-Helper doesn't get it to construct the Facade helper file. 
Then, when I use it, as  `\QRCode::url('...')`, get `Class QRCode does not exists` Exception.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't work. After inspecting the OctoberCMS `composer.json` file, and comparing it to Laravel's `composer.json` file, there is no autoloading setup in the OctoberCMS scripts.

The Laravel `composer.json` contains the following to enable automatic package discovery:

```
"scripts": [
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ],
    ...
]
```

You may be able to add this to your OctoberCMS install, however, I don't know if this will behave normally